# Variable passed but exception still thrown?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create and pass a data array:

```
public function home()
{


    $data['page'] = 'home';
    $data['table'] = 'pageData';
    $data['temp'] = 'temp_1';

    $this->template($data);


}


    public function template($data)
{

    $this->load->model("model_get");


    $data['results'] = $this->model_get->getData($data);

    $this->load->view('template', $data);


}
```

This is the template view:

```
<?php

$this->load->view('header');

$this->load->view('nav', $data);

$data['results'] = $results;

$this->load->view($temp, $data);

$this->load->view('footer');

?>
```

It throws an exception for undefined variable at:

```
$this->load->view('nav', $data);
```

but still loads the view and completes all the if statements inside it and loads the view from the name stored in `$temp`.

Why does it throw the exception?

Comment: Obviously you need to check the data variable and see what it returns. Use print_r

Comment: the exemption says its undefined

Comment: all it does is echo out that it is undefined, but it uses the variable and in side of xamp it worked fine, i did add the nav menu seperate, it not exact after the error but it is until the error, this is off the server, and like i said it still loads the content

Comment: I think it's scope of variable thats an issue.

Comment: how would i correct the scope issue, redefine it?

Comment: Try returning data in your function. Are these two code snippets different files? Also I don't see any of the functions being used in your second code snippet.

Comment: yes, it starts in the controller loads template which in turn loads the view nav and the view stored in $temp defined at the beginning, the model view controller architecture is the one native to CodeIgniter

Comment: echo every thing right in the function

Answer (score 0):

You haven't populated $data in that view to load a second view.  Your code is too vaguely named to really understand what it's supposed to be doing but let's break it down.

```
public function home()
{
$data['page'] = 'home';
$data['table'] = 'pageData';
$data['temp'] = 'temp_1';
$this->template($data);
}


public function template($data)
{
$this->load->model("model_get");
$data['results'] = $this->model_get->getData($data);
//I assume getData takes a table name and returns all the data
//This only works because you're taking all the data passed from the first function
//in the function above.
$this->load->view('template', $data);
}


<?php
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('nav', $data);
//At this point $data is empty. You have available $results, $page, $table and $temp
//because they were passed from the template function above.
$this->load->view('nav', $results);
//The line above is what it appears you need, rather than $data.
$data['results'] = $results;
//You've repopulated $data here but now all it contains is $results.
$this->load->view($temp, $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
?>
```

What you're misunderstanding is $data is not persistent, when you pass it to a view by loading a view with $data as the second parameter it breaks down into it's components, so $data itself is no longer available.